# Rewriting the output of a file download field

Tags: views, 8

I have a content type with two fields, one pdf field which will be downloaded using the [Download File](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjQ2pOdzeDdAhUmrVkKHSGhAiEQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fdownload_file&usg=AOvVaw2QACM6obDwjpKSeXZ1JsO0) module which provides a formatter (file download) to automatically download the pdf file with one click and one image field linked to the pdf field, using the [Linked Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field) module. This works in the node without problems. 
The problem is when trying to rewrite the results of the image field in Views.
I set the file field with the "File download fomatter" and exclude it from display.
Then, I try to rewrite results of the image field like this

```
<a href="{{ file_download_field | striptags}}">{{ image_field }}</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{ file_download_field.url }}">{{ image_field }}</a>
```

but this is not working.

The files are stored in the folder

```
[root]/file-download/download/public[node:field_file_download:entity:fid]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the File field display like if you don't exclude it from Display? You only want to use the URL then you should set the `Formatter` of that field accordingly.

Comment: I just want the pdf file to download with one click, if you show it, it will open in a browser tab using the default reader in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "File download fomatter" you're using doesn't output just the path to the file, it's a more complex formatter and you can't use it in your case as a path to download the file.

In Drupal 8 there is a separate Field in File Views called **URI** that you need to use.

[image: File URI settings in Drupal 8]

Depending on which Drupal 8 version you're using you'll see only the formatter `File URI` and you need to tick the option **Display the file download URI** to get the link you can use in an anchor href attribute later when overriding fields.

**Do not** enable `Link this field to the file download URL`, this outputs complex anchor HTML, not just the path that you're after.

You can exclude it from display, position it above the image field and `Rewrite results` for the image:

`<a href="{{ uri }}">{{ image_field }}</a>`

or let Drupal link it:

[image: Rewrite results Views Field output Link]

Comment: Thanks for your answer prkos. I don't have the file URI field available in my Drupal 8.6.1 installation. Do you know what's the reason for that? I have: 'Table of files, Video, Generic file, RSS enclosure, URL to file and Audio' as formatter options in my view. URL to file did the trick, outputting it as a custom link.

Comment: I'm also checking on D8.6.1. Which Field are you using? It's a bit confusing I guess because the Field is called `URI` from the `File` Category, and then within the field the Formatter has a similar name `File URI`. I see more options under Formatter for that field on my D8.4.4 instance but I probably have different field configuration there too. Are you using a Field from Content Category? That is pulling information from the node, and not directly from the Files table in the database.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a field that I'm pulling from the content. Views does not any 'File-related' fields available

Comment: Is it File type or Content type Views? If it's Content then you'd have to introduce a Relationship to File data to be able to see that additional File category with Fields from Files database table.

Comment: I get this message when trying to add a Relationship: "Configure Relationship: Broken/missing handler" - "A file that is associated with this node, usually because it is in a field on the node.

The handler for this item is broken or missing. The following details are available:

Enabling the appropriate module may solve this issue. Otherwise, check to see if there is a module update available."

Comment: What Relationship did you add? Was it working at first? Did you disable any modules recently?

Comment: I added File (A file that is associated with this node, usually because it is in a field on the node.) This is the error message: Notice: Undefined index: id in Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsHandlerManager->getHandler() (line 104 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/ViewsHandlerManager.php). It accepts it if I add the relationship to the field, but it doesn't show the File URI option in the file download field. I did not disable any module.

Comment: I guess I could just add this download attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp to the field template and that's it. But that is stuff for another question. I needed it, in order to write something: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/how-to-rewrite-the-output-of-views-fields/. Thanks for your help prkos, you're very nice!

Comment: By the way, there's also the possibility of creating a viewmode and displaying it with Views.

Comment: Yes, of course, viewmodes are very useful, and can be used in Views. But you either have some bugs in your site or maybe we're not talking about the same thing. You have to separate two different things, Field name, and Formatter. In this particular case they are named very similar, Field called `URI` from Category `File`, and Formatter _within_ that field called `File URI`. There may be other Fields related to files that have that Formatter, but what I'm describing is for the particular Field called URI. Try and find that Field and add it to your Views, and investigate why the Broken handler.

Comment: Hi prkos, thanks for clarifying this. The realtionship is to the field_yourfield:target_id. I added the file URI field set it as formatter File URI and added the relationship to this field. It basically does the same as chosing the file field and selecting URL to the file as formatter. However, it opened my eyes in other aspects :). I'm gonna post another question to find out how to add the download attribute to the link. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: haha, you're welcome! I'm glad to help :)